# What's the best way to create a pdf document with charts and in a decent quality?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf-generation, jspdf, jsreport

First of all, I want to apologize for my English, I know my grammar is not the best, I'm not a native speaker so sometimes I have a hard time finding the right words or trying to explain the things I have in mind. So if you have a problem understanding what I want, please let me know and I'll try to be clearer.

I'm making a web app, the backend is made in PHP.
I need to create some kind of pdf-report for the users with charts, tables, pictures, and I need it to be decent (Quality and Style)

I don't know if the best option is a javascript library, 'cause I've found some libraries, but these make not really good looking pdfs.

So I was looking for a javascript library, but nothing seems to fit my requeriments.

I'll give you some pictures in order for you to have a better idea about what I want:

- [Sales report:](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photography-quarterly-sales-report-accounting-studying-graphic-black-pen-image38464372) This was the closest I could find to what I want.
- [Another sales report](https://d2htdayykptdg9.cloudfront.net/sites/550f21d98e6927763a0003dd/theme/images/screenshots/agent-report.png?1515403810) Something like this
- [Invoice](https://dribbble.com/shots/2691501-Invoice-Free-Template) I need something that allows me to make a really good looking  design for the document, similar to this invoice

I'm really getting tired of looking and found nothing... It's been almost 2 months now, maybe more.

So my first idea was to use a javascript library that could convert html to pdf, but I was so naive and I didn't know how hard it was to convert html to pdf and without messing with the structure of the elements (The visual organization)
I first tried jsPDF by MrRio, but it doesn't support css (Something that I really need) or the charts (If the charts are pictures, it works fine, but if they are generated with a library like chartJS or highcharts it won't work).

I tried with some similar plugins but all of them had similar problems

Here is the link for [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) and their [git](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Then I found jsreport, I did a really nice thing in their playground and it worked perfectly. The problem is it needs NodeJS and my Site is made in nodeJS, and I don't know if there is a way to use jsreport with php and if there is I'm not sure if it will work as nice as it did in their playground.
Something that I just tought about if there will be a way that use nodeJS only for this feature, I don't know it is not recommended or something, need to find more about this, idk what you guys think.

Jsreport can use multiple recipes like PhantomJS to generate the PDF

I've found other plugins but they are also for nodeJS only.

Here is [jsreport](https://jsreport.net/) site

Then I tried again jsPDF but this time using it along with [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and it worked almost fine, but the quality decreases a lot and the text cannot be selected or copied. I managed to increase the quality a bit, but nothing further that.

I have other ideas, something related to the print option from the browsers, but haven't found anything good.
The other idea that I don't know if it possible, it's making some kind of document like a template and then somehow add the user data inside that template, to finally have a pdf but with the users data.

[Read this](http://blog.stahlmandesign.com/export-html-to-pdf-how-hard-can-it-be/), here is some related info.

So, the reason I want this feature it's because most of the clients that use my Web App, require this function. So I can't migrate my app to Node or Rails, because it will take a really long time, and I don't have that time right now, so I don't know what are my options. The solution doesn't need to be free, but if it is, it will be great, because I don't have a big budget for a really expensive plugin.

Thank you for reading my question, I really need help with this, so let me know everything you have in mind, every answer is appreciated even if I've already tried it, because maybe you can came up with a different solution using something that I have used already.

Comment: pdfmake.js is the best library for pdf generation.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your Html page with Highcharts or whatever charts you want to get and then use this tool [WkHtmltoPDF](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)